# Finding a geometric series for $\frac{1}{(1 + x)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, geometric-series

I'm asked to find a geometric series for $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1 + x)^2}$, I integrate it first and I get $F(x) = \int{\frac{1}{(1 + x)^2}dx} = \frac{1}{-2(1 - (-x))}$

Since $\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$, $F(x) = \frac{-1}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2}x^n$

If I derive that, $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} n x^{n-1}}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n (n + 1) x^n}{2}$

But my textbook says that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n + 1) x^n$

Obviously those 2 things are pretty different (notice the index). What did I get wrong?

Comment: Oops, I forgot some really important paranthesis in my question! Double checked now, the question should be correct.

Comment: Would you wish to check your F(x)?

Comment: @Maam Indeed, that $1/2$ shouldn't be there. How about the index problem though? How can you get into that form keeping $n=0$?

Comment: @winter: the antiderivative is only well defined up to a constant. You need to determine the $n=0$ term by plugging in $x=0$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip That's pretty much what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Original question**:

> find a geometric series for  $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

As you wrote, $$\frac{1}{1-y} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n$$

Substituting $y=-x^2$, we have

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$$

**Edited question**:

> find a geometric series for  $$g(x) = \frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^2}$$

Recall that $$(1+x)^2 = 1+2x+x^2$$

As you wrote, $$\frac{1}{1-y} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n$$

Substituting $y=-2x-x^2$, we have

$$g(x)= \frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^2}=\frac{1}{1-\left(-2x-x^2\right)} = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(2x+x^2\right)^n$$

Comment: You mean it's about $1/(1+x)^2$, not $1/(1+x^2)$?

Comment: Yes it's about $1/(1+x)^2$, just noticed the error in my comment.

Comment: Thanks for this alternate approach, it's quite interesting! I was asked to solve it using differentiation but I'm glad to be able to learn about this technique as well.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The geometric series is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + \ldots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

In the step of integration, it should be $$F(x)= \int \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \mathrm{d} x =-  \frac {1}{1+x} + \mathrm{C}$$
You've got an extra factor of $\frac 12$.
For setting the index correctly, you need to find $\mathrm C$ by initial value of $n$.